# How to navigate to Text Services and Input Languages in Windows 10 1909

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages, control-panel

After having added a second keyboard layout to Windows, I wanted to turn off its hotkeys to switch between them, like `Left Alt+Shift`, and `Ctrl+Shift`. I knew about the **Text Services and Input Languages** dialog but in my current version of Windows 10 (1909, build 18363.1082), I simply couldn't find it. It is this dialog:

[image: Text Services and Input Languages dialog in Windows]

Although I found what I need via:

`rundll32.exe Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL input.dll,,{C07337D3-DB2C-4D0B-9A93-B722A6C106E2}`

I would like to know how to call it up without having to know that command, like when I am at someone else's computer, or on a "vanilla" Windows install.

I searched the Windows 10 Settings as well as Control Panel. It apparently used to be here:

Control Panel > Clock, Language, and Region > Change input methods > Advanced settings

but I don't see that now, even after hunting in the new names, like **Region**.

Am I blind? Can anyone show me the GUI way to navigate to this dialog in the current version of Windows?

Comment: There is an applet named "Region"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Windows 10 you can find it in:

*Settings > Devices > Typing > Advanced keyboard settings >
Input language hot keys*.

(A bit long, but it gets there.)

**Edit**

Note by user pallxk:

In Windows 11, it's
*Settings > Time & Language > Typing > Advanced keyboard settings > Input language hot keys*.

Comment: Yes! Thank you.

Comment: In Windows 11, it's *Settings* -> *Time & Language* -> *Typing* -> *Advanced keyboard settings* -> *Input language hot keys*.